# Problems to make tests on Django

Tags: python, django, testing, integration-testing, bdd

I am new to tests and the tutorials are not helping me at all (they are either old or not appliable to my case).

I want to test some functionalities on Django. Let's say I want to test this:

```
class PageDetailView(AuthorizedView, PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    """
    Page Detail View

    This view will load the whole dataset for a Page
    """
    permission_required = 'view_page'
    # This is temporary. The idea is to redirect user to a call_to_action page
    redirect_field_name = 'panel'
    model = Page
    template_name = 'twist/entity_topic_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PageDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        evaluated_news = EvaluatedNews(self.object,
                                   self.request.user)
        context['evaluated_news'] = evaluated_news()
        context['modules'] = [
            'sources',
            'ranking',
            'topics',
            'locations_coord',
            'terms',
            'news',
            'relations',
            'twitterterms',
            'twittertweets',
            'twitterheatmap'
            ]
        return context
```

How can I apply a test?

This is how the url is set:

```
url(r'detail/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$', views.PageDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

-- edit

For example, right now I am stuck in something that was supposed to be basic...

**test:**

import unittest
from django.test import RequestFactory
from twist.views import *

```
class PageDetailTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get(self):
         self.user = User.objects.create_user(username="admin", password="123")
         request = RequestFactory().get("/detail/2/")
         view = PageDetailView.as_view(template_name="twist/entity_topic_detail.html")
         response = view(request)
         self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

**error:**

```
'if test_func(request.user):                                          │~                                                          
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user''
```

Comment: What do you want to test _exactly_ ?

Comment: I would like to make a first "hello world" of testing and make sure the page loads, for example.

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/)?

Comment: @shuttle87, I am reading it now and I believe it fits in the "not appliable" case.

Comment: If you can explain why that is in the "not applicable" category you will probably improve your question substantially.

Comment: If you look closely, you will notice the tutorial does not class based views. The ones I found online haven't helped much either.

Comment: @Ricardo it is happening because the request you are passing to the view does not have user attribute. You are assing user to Test class instead of request object

Comment: @Ricardo I have edited my answer, see if it helps

Comment: the short answer why you get the error is because `RequestFactory` does not execute middleware, so no `user` attribute gets added to the `request` object.  @hspandher provides a solution   ...in the long run I'd advise against making too many of these kind of (integration rather than unit) tests though.

Comment: Thank you for the help. =) It ain't really clarified in the available documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the easiest way is to write integration tests that test the whole view flow. That can easily be done using django test client:-

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestPageDetailView(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.id = '234' # some valid id for your use cacse
        self.url = "/detail/{0}/".format(url = self.id)

        self.response = self.client.get(self.url)

    def test_returns_valid_response(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)

    def test_returns_correct_context_variables(self):
        expected_context_vars = ['sources', 'ranking', 'topic'] # ...

        map(lambda context_var: self.assertIn(context_var, self.response.context), expected_context_vars)
```

Obviously, it's no way exhaustive, and you need to handle authentication and stuff but something on these lines.

Although, if you want to unit test some method separately, you need to get hold of class instance which is made in function returned by `as_view`. Often I prefer integration tests to test views, but sometimes if you really need to unit test some portions, you could do something like --

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

class TestViewMixin(object):

    def create_view_object(self, view, request, args = [], kwargs = {}):
        view_object = view()
        view_object.request, view_object.args, view_object.kwargs = request, args, kwargs

        return view_object

class TestUnitPageDetailView(TestViewMixin, TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.id = '234'
        self.request = HttpRequest()
        self.request.method = 'GET'

        self.view = self.create_view_object(PageDetailView, self.request, kwargs = {'pk': self.id})
```

Now, you can test view as you would test a normal class.

As far as your **Edited answer** is concerned, you need to assign `user` to request, instead of test class instance

```
request.user = User.objects.create_user(username="admin", password="123")
```

instead of

```
self.user = User.objects.create_user(username="admin", password="123")
```

Comment: Yes it helped. Thank you.